# How do i scp folder download?

Tags: java, scp

I used 'SCP' Method "download()".
However, This Method is file download.
I want to know that folder download...
please answer me.. thank you.

//example

```
private boolean readFolderSCP(String localFolder, String remoteFolder)
{
   ssh.authPassword(param.getUsername(), param.getPasswd());
   File scpfile = new File(remoteFolder);
   if (scpfile.isDirectory())
   {
     String scpfiles[] = scpfile.list();
     for (int i=0; i<scpfiles.length; i++)
     {
        File remotefile = new File(remoteFolder+"/"+scpfiles[i]);
        if (remotefile.isFile())
        {
          ssh.newSCPFileTransfer().download(remoteFolder+"/"+scpfiles[i], new FileSystemFile(localFolder+"/"+scpfiles[i])); 
        } 
     }
   }    
   return true;
}
```

that's right?

Comment: what library are you using to do SCP?

Answer (score 0):

SCP is not really designed to do directory listings, as it is pretty much just a file copy protocol.  Thus it is very hard to get a bunch of files from a directory unless you know exactly what your looking for.

Your code as written is certainly not going to be able to get a remote directory listing, since the initial call to `new File(remoteFolder)` will look at your local system, instead of the remote system.

SFTP has the same security as SCP (it's based on the SSH protocol), and includes all of the commands for FTP, including directory listings.  I would check your library documentation and try to write your command using SFTP instead of SCP.